# Batch save of vector files in specific projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-layer

I have a group of multiple vector files in EPSG:3857 Pseudo-Mercator, and I want to export them to WGS84 53S, EPSG:32753.

Ideally I would like to select all of the files to export, select the directory to save them to, and then have them export with the same filenames, perhaps appended with '53S' at the end.

Comment: Although you tagged this with qgis, this task is probably better handled using gdal and shell scripting. What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using windows and QGIS 3.16.8

Comment: This can be done using pyqgis, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408327/batch-processing-contour-lines-in-qgis/408333#408333  to get started

Comment: Or use batch mode of the reproject tool in QGIS